# What is wrong in below script?

Tags: sql, sap-ase

```
declare @param int

    if not exists (select * from PostingDefinition where id='postnbr' and map_addr like 'Subledger')
    begin
        execute GetNewRowId @table_name = 'PostingDefinition', @max_row = @param output
        insert into PostingDefinition values (@param,'postnbr','Subledger','Posting #','int')
    end
    if not exists (select * from PostingDefinition where id='source' and map_addr like 'Subledger')
    begin
        execute GetNewRowId @table_name = 'PostingDefinition', @max_row = @param output
        insert into PostingDefinition values (@param,'source','Subledger','Source','char')
    end
go
```

When I run this script on Sybase 15.7 it gives me an error:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1:
Server 't6', Line 4:
PostingDefinition not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check
whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1:
Server 't6', Line 7:
PostingDefinition not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check
whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output).
```

If I remove the `go` statement at the end of script then it works perfectly fine.

Note: `GetNewRowId` in above script is a procedure that I have defined which generated the next row id of table(a way of generating `primary key`)

Comment: Are you connected to the good database (the one `PostingDefinition` belongs to) ?

Comment: Yes, I can see this table and it's content if I connect to db via Sybase Central. As I said in the question itself if I remove the 'go' statement then this script will succeed